# Having trouble in showing alert box for wrong credentials in react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I want to show an alert box if username and password is not matching. I am sending a post request from react(using axios)to nodeJS to check for email and password. Everything is working fine if credentials are correct but it is not doing anything if it is wrong(that's understandable) but I want to show an alert when it is not correct. Why is my code not working and what would be the correct way to do it?
This is react code below:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import "./LogIn.css";
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';
import axios from "../axios.js";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

function SignUp() {

    // States for registration
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    
    // Handling the email change
    const handleEmail = (e) => {
        
        setEmail(e.target.value);
        
    };

    // Handling the password change
    const handlePassword = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
        
    };

    // Handling the form submission
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        if (email === '' || password === '') {
            setError(true);
        } else {
            setError(false);
            axios.post('./login',{
                email,password
            }).then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                if(res.request.status === 200){
                    navigate(`/profile/${res.data.name}`);
                }else{
                    alert("Username/Password is incorrect.")
                };
            });
        }
    };

    // // Showing error message if error is true
    const errorMessage = () => {
        return (
        <div
            className="error"
            style={{
            display: error ? '' : 'none',
            }}>
            <h4>Please enter all the fields.</h4>
        </div>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="form">

            <form>
                <h1>Log In</h1>
                <p>It's quick and easy.</p>
                {/* Labels and inputs for form data */}
                <div className="input_field">
                    <MailIcon className="icon" fontSize="small"/>
                    <input onChange={handleEmail} className="input" placeholder="Email"
                        value={email} type="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="input_field">
                    <LockIcon className="icon" fontSize="small"/>
                    <input onChange={handlePassword} className="last-input" placeholder="Password"
                        value={password} type="password" />
                </div>
                {/* Calling to the methods */}
                <div className="messages">
                    {errorMessage()}
                </div>
                <br/> <br/>
                <button onClick={handleSubmit} className="btn" type="submit">
                    Log In
                </button>
            </form>

            
        </div>
);

}

export default SignUp
```

This is nodeJs code:

```js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import Cors from "cors";
const app=express();
const port= process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:admin15@cluster0.gmg3q.mongodb.net/NotScrapDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

const userSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
});

const User= mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hello World!Welcome to NOTSCRAP backend");
});

app.get("/register", (req, res)=>{
    res.send("registered");
});

app.post("/register", (req,res)=>{
    const newUser = req.body;
    User.create(newUser, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        } else{
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res)=>{
    const user_email = req.body.email;
    const user_password = req.body.password;
    if(User.findOne({email: user_email}, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        } else{
            if(foundUser){
                if(foundUser.password === user_password){
                    res.send(foundUser);
                }
            }
        }
    }))
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${port}`);
})
```

Issue is in handleSubmit of the react code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should probably keep a variable:

```js
const [credentialError, setCredentialError] = useState('');
....
```

And rather than calling alert from the error setting the value for this `credentialError` variable.

```js
...
                console.log(res);
                if(res.request.status === 200){
                    setCredentialError('')
                    navigate(`/profile/${res.data.name}`);
                }else{
                    setCredentialError('Credential Error (Your custom message)')
                };
...
```

Then use this variable to show a message in the interface.

Comment: If the credentials are wrong then nothing is working because if the credentials are wrong then even my console.log is not working which is placed inside .then(). Its like if id/password is not matching then in that case .then() is not getting executed.